# MacBook Bluetooth won't switch on

Tags: macos, mac, bluetooth, big-sur, airpods

My MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, two Thunderbolt 3 ports) has been giving me Bluetooth issues for some time.

It often drops the connection with my AirPods and sometimes when I try to switch Bluetooth off and then on again -- it just doesn't switch on. What seems to resolve the issue temporarily is to restart the computer.

I took my laptop in to a certified repair centre to get my keyboard replaced (it had a faulty keyboard too), and as a bonus the technician said he'd have a look at my Bluetooth module. According to him there are no issues with the hardware, so it must be a software issue.

On his recommendation I performed a clean installation of Big Sur, which involved backing up important files, wiping the internal storage and starting over.

After doing that I still have the exact same issues as before! Could the problem be my AirPods Pro? I recently got them, and they work fine with my iPhone. Any ideas would be super appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [resetting your AirPods](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT209463)? Can you clarify the bluetooth issues you're experiencing?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I haven’t reset them, I don’t think! I’ll do that and report back. 
There seems to be more than one issue I’m  experiencing. First, my Mac’s connection to my AirPods sometimes disconnects randomly, requiring me to manually re-connect them. Second, the Bluetooth on my Mac sometimes doesn’t switch on, after being switched off: the toggle in the menu bar is just unresponsive. Hope that helps!

Comment: Update: I have reset my AirPods but the issue remains. It connects fine to my iPhone but not to my MacBook.